# html drop down list event

Tags: jquery

I have a  control and when the user select a value, it triggers a jquery event that sends an ajax postback. Its option values look like this:

```
<option value="select new month ... ">select new month ... </option>
<option value="____________________  ">____________________  </option>
<option value=" "> </option>
<option value="March 2011">March 2011</option>
```

For now, the user selects an option and the when the postback completes, the value showing in the drop down is the last value selected. What I'd like to do when the postback is complete is show the first option again.

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select option:first-child').attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('...', {}, function(){
    $('#yourSelect option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
});
```